# python check user input is day of the week

Tags: python, input, confirm, dayofweek, days

I am attempting to define a function that asks the user which days of the week they are available. I need their input to be saved into a list for future use. I want to ensure they are entering the day of the week properly and that it is in the correct format. I have tried various ways but cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
daysWeek = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]

def daysInput(message):
    print(daysWeek)
    z = False
    while z == False:
        i = list(input(message).strip().title().replace(",", " ").split(" "))
        print(i)
        varify = 0
        for day in i:
            for dow in daysWeek:
                if day == dow:
                    varify += 1
                else:
                    varify = 0
        if varify == 0:
            print("Invalid entry")
        else:
            z = True
            return i
```

Answer (score 1):

When `varify += 1` is executed, and a next iteration executes, `varify` is set back to 0 even though the input day had matched with a correct day in the previous iteration. That means that unless you enter only the *last* day (`Sun`), the input will be rejected.

Secondly, if a day is found, and the next day from the input is checked, you'll destroy the previous result, by clearing `varify` again, even though a match will be found in a next iteration.

You need to implement the logic that for *all* inputs, *some* day of the week should match with it. You can do this a lot easier with the `all` function and the `in` operator:

```
daysWeek = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]

def daysInput(message):
    print(daysWeek)
    while True:
        inp = list(input(message).strip().title().replace(",", " ").split(" "))
        print(inp)
        if all(day in daysWeek for day in inp):
            return inp
        print("Invalid entry")

daysInput("Enter some days of the week: ")
```

Comment: The reason I had cleared varify after each pass was because ALL inputs must be in daysWeek, but not all days. So Tue, wed, fri, sat should work. But something with an error like Mon, tup, wed should fail once it hits tup.